# Month end beta calculation of a stock

Tags: r

I have market returns  and stock returns for a large set of data and i was trying to calculate the beta of stock on every month end.

For eg I have the following data:

```
dateoffset  relian       niftyreturns
20000103    0.034484    0.075484
20000104    0.019205    0.029205
20000105    -1.026179   -0.026179
20000106    0.413661    0.013661
20000107    -0.002658   -0.002658
20000110    0.01218     0.01248
20000111    -0.037019   -0.037019
20000112    0.033259    0.133259
20000113    -0.002093   -0.002093
20000114    0.000833    0.000833
```

Say I need to calculate the `var(niftyreturns)` for date `20000103-20000131` and again `var(niftyreturns)` for date `20000201-20000229` and so on. All help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's a `data.table`:

```
dt[, list(variance = var(niftyreturns)),
     by = list(year_month = as.integer(dateoffset/100))]
```

Comment: Thanks..eddie.. I also found an interesting piece of code .https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/PerformanceAnalytics/R/CAPM.beta.R?view=markup&root=returnanalytics&pathrev=2303